# Levenberg-Marquardt in python with constraints

Tags: python-2.7, levenberg-marquardt

Is there any good way to add constraits into levenberg-marquadt routine in python? What i found so far is mostly changing the errorfunction to something like

```
def errorfunction(params, PSD_data, bins):
if (params[0] < 0) or (params[1] < 0) or (params[2] < 0):
    return (PSD_data - PSD_fit(params, bins))*1000
else:
    return PSD_data - PSD_fit(params, bins)
```

But even then it is possible to get wrong results, eg. params[0] to be negativ! Any sugggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lmfit library for this:

http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/

It supports constraints and it is build on top of scipy.